# How send data from parent to child with VueJS?

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.8

I am learning VueJS2 to use with Laravel, and I ended up having some difficulties to send data from parent to child and return an event. Yesterday I did several searches on Google and here on the Stack.

I'm trying to tell the child that the user clicked the on parent component submit button, the child must pick up the data from the inputs and return it to the parent for to send.

userForm.blade.php

```
// Only part of the content
<b-form method="PATCH" action="/users/store">
  <b-userform to-send-data="sendCall"></b-userform>
</b-form>
```

formComponent.vue

```
// Part of <script>
data() {
  return {
    senCall: false
  };
},
methods: {
  getChildData(e) {
    this.sendCall = true;
    console.log("FormComponent: 1");
    console.log(e);
  },
  sendForm(data) {
    console.log("FormComponent: 2");
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

userFormComponent.vue

```
// Part of <Script>
props: {
  toSendData: false
},
methods: {
  sendData: function() {
    console.log("UserForm: 1");
  }
},
watch: {
  toSendData: function() {
    console.log("Change? " + this.toSendData);
  }
}
```

I tried change `to-send-data="sendCall"` to `:to-send-data="sendCall"` but received the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "sendCall" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

More complete code:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv0z2mlwy3)

Thanks for the help.

---

EDIT:

With undefined help I read more about slots/scoped slots on VueJS documentation and in another community a user gave me a [link](http://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-vs-data/) to better understand the data flow of parents and childs.

To the code to work I removed `to-send-data="sendCall"` from Blade file and put it in the `<slot :to-send-data="sendCall"></slot>` on the formComponent.vue file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a demo for slot way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
  <script>
  Vue.component('b-form', {
    data: function() {
      return { sendData: 'hi' }
    },
    template: `<div>
    <slot :sendData="sendData"></slot>
   </div>`,
  })

  Vue.component('b-userform', {
    props: ['sendData'],
    template: '<div>{{sendData}}</div>',
  })

  new Vue({
    template: `<b-form>
    <template v-slot:default="slotScope">
      <b-userform :sendData="slotScope.sendData"></b-userform>
    </template>
   </b-form>`,
  }).$mount('#app')
  </script>
</body>
```

You can do this by four ways:

1. Put the 'sendData' in 'userForm.blade.php'
2. Or use ref on 'formComponent' in 'userForm.blade.php'

```
<b-form method="PATCH" ref="parentCom" action="/users/store">
  <b-userform :to-send-data="$refs.parentCom.sendCall"></b-userform>
</b-form>
```

3. Or in 'userFormComponent' directly access the $parent
   `this.$parent.sendData`
4. Or use 'slot' like this:

```
// in formComponent
<div>
  <slot v-bind:sendData="sendData">

  </slot>
</div>
```

```
// in userForm.blade.php

<b-form method="PATCH" action="/users/store">
  <template v-slot:default="slotScope">
     <b-userform :to-send-data="slotScope.sendData"></b-userform>
  </template>
</b-form>
```

; if your vuejs's version < 2.6 use the 'slot-scope';

Comment: Using slot and var on blade file (with or without v-bind) did not work, the toSendData in child was left undefined. The two other methods (such as $ref and this.$parent) I'm trying to avoid because in the documentation it says it's for cases that need to "bending Vue’s rules" and I think passing data from parent to child is not the case. I'm sorry and correct me if I'm wrong about using these two methods, like I said I'm learning ... xD (Vue version is 2.6.10)

Comment: Yes, you are right. ' $ref and this.$parent' is not recommanded way. Use slot maybe is the best way for this case. I paste a snippet .It works.

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't no why yesterday on the first try with slot didn't work... But after I read the docs and learn more about slot scope and how to use it, I changed the code and works fine.